# Add the data to the same row in new column in excel using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

[image]I have an an excel file with column Test where I have hello and hello1 as two rows. After performing certain operations I get data which I want to add to the same rows in new columns Test1 and Test2.

I have below code

```
df = pd.read_excel(input_file)
    for index, row in df.iterrows(): #Iterating on column Test
        value = row["Test"]
        print (value) # hello[![enter image description here][1]][1]
        matching_rows = some_operation(input_file, column_name, value)     
        print (matching_rows) # hi, hello, how, are , you, I, am , testing, this
        ab = (matching_rows["Test1"]) # ab = hi, hello, how, are , you
        abc = (matching_rows['Test2']) # ab = I, am , testing, this
```

I'm not sure what would be the next code to get the data as shown in the below picture.

Answer (score 0):

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    value = row["Test"]
    matching_rows = some_operation(input_file, column_name, value)
    ab = matching_rows["Test1"].tolist()
    abc = matching_rows["Test2"].tolist()

    df.at[index, 'Test1'] = ', '.join(ab_value for ab_value in ab if ab_value in ab)
    df.at[index, 'Test2'] = ', '.join(str(abc_value) for abc_value in abc if abc_value in abc)
    df.to_excel(inputfile, index=False)
```

Comment: You are working with array and each time you change the length of an array, the whole array is copied. This is highly inefficient (though very close to your initial approach). I would recommend you not to loop trough your data and make changes to the frame many times, but do one major change once you gathered all your data, as you can see in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is rather complex for what you are trying to achieve, so I assume that it could be much easier. However, I stuck to your approch and this is a way to do it:

```
def some_operations(column_data):
    op1 = column_data + "_operation_done_1"
    op2 = column_data + "_operation_done_2"
    return op1, op2

df = pd.DataFrame(["hello", "hello1"], columns=["Test"])
df

df[["Test1", "Test2"]] = some_operations(df["Test"])
```

**Note:** Since the excel source doesn't really matter here, I just used a DataFrame that is easier to copy and paste.

[image]

Comment: Not sure not working!!

Comment: ? This works fine for me. Is there an error or do you expect another output?

Comment: Yeah, anyways thank you so much for your answer! I did found my way.